# Polya's urn (martingale)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, martingales, conditional-expectation

Suppose you have an urn containing one red ball and one green ball. You draw one at random; if the ball is red, put it back in the urn with an additional red ball , otherwise put it back and add a green ball . Repeat this procedure and let the random variable $X_n$ be the number of red balls in the urn after n draws.
Let $Y_n=\frac{1}{n+2}X_n$. Find $\mathbb{\mathbb{\textrm{E}}}\left(Y_{n}\right)$ and prove that $Y_n$ is a martingale with respect to $X_n$.

---

MY ATTEMPT:

We have $\mathbb{\mathbb{\textrm{E}}}\left(\left.X_{n+1}\right|X_{n}\right)=X_{n}+\dfrac{X_{n}}{n+2}=\dfrac{n+3}{n+2}X_{n}$, so

$\mathbb{\mathbb{\textrm{E}}}\left(\left.Y_{n+1}\right|X_{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n+3}\mathbb{\mathbb{\textrm{E}}}\left(\left.X_{n+1}\right|X_{n}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n+3}\cdot\dfrac{n+3}{n+2}X_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\cdot X_{n}=Y_{n}$

It's ok?

And, can you help me to find $\mathbb{\mathbb{\textrm{E}}}\left(Y_{n}\right)$?

Comment: The martingale property is $E(Y_{n+1}\mid X_0,\dots, X_n)=Y_n$, not $E(Y_{n+1}\mid X_n)=Y_n$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland But above calculations stay the same. In particular, $E[R_{n+1}|X_n,...,X_1]=X_n/(n+2).$

Comment: @ir7 So OP has to prove $Y_n$ has Markov property?

Comment: @BCLC It's already done, but not said explicitly. The way to prove Markov property is indeed to calculate the conditional expectation on all variables (history). If we get lucky and the expression we obtain as result is only dependent on the latest variable, then we are done. The two conditional expectations (one on all variables, the other on the latest) are equal.

Comment: @ir7 How to go about showing $E[R_{n+1} | X_n, ..., X_1] = \frac{X_n}{n+2}$? If $| X_n$ only, then fine. But with all the others...?

Answer (score 5):

Looks good, as indeed
$$ X_{n+1} = X_n + R_{n+1},$$
where $R_{i}$ denotes the indicator variable that takes value $1$ if color of the $i$-th ball extracted is red, and $0$ if green. By definition we have that the urn contains $X_n$ red and $n+2-X_n$ green balls after $n$ extractions. Then the conditional probability given $X_n$ of a red ball on the $n+1$-th extraction (equal to the conditional expectation given $X_n$ of $R_{n+1}$ that we need) is $$\frac{X_n}{n+2}=Y_n.$$
We also observe that
$$ X_n = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n R_i. $$
Taking expectation we get:
$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ X_n\right] = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{E}\left[ R_i\right].$$
As all $R_i$ have the same distribution as $R_1$, we get:
$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ R_i\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[ R_1\right] =\frac{1}{2},$$
for all $i\in \{1,\ldots , n\}$.
Our indicator variables have the same distribution due to the fact that the sequence of variables $R_1,\ldots, R_n$ is [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), as its joint distribution
$$\mathbf{P}\left(R_1=c_1,\ldots, R_n=c_n\right)   $$ $$= \mathbf{P}\left(R_1=c_1\right)\mathbf{P}\left(R_2=c_2 | R_1=c_1\right) \ldots\mathbf{P}\left(R_n=c_n | R_1=c_1,\ldots, R_{n-1}=c_{n-1}\right) $$ 
$$ = \frac{c!(n-c)!}{(n+1)!}$$ depends on $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ only through the number of red balls $c$, $c=c_1+\ldots + c_n$.

To conclude, we have $\mathbf{E}[X_n]=(n+2)/2$, so
$$\mathbf{E}[Y_n]=1/2.$$
This can also be seen directly as we already know that $Y_n$ is a martingale, so ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967719/if-x-n-is-a-martingale-then-ex-n-x-n-1-0))
$$\mathbf{E}[Y_n]=\mathbf{E}[Y_{n-1}]=\ldots = \mathbf{E}[Y_1]=1/2.$$

Comment: Then $\mathbf{E}\left[ X_n\right] = \frac{n}{2}$. And therefore, $\mathbf{E}\left[ Y_n\right] = \frac{1}{n+2} \frac{n}{2}$. It's ok??

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot the existing red ball in the urn.

Comment: Also, note Byron Schmuland's comment. But the calculations look the same whether conditioning on X_n only or on all X_n,...,X_1 (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: How do the $R_i$'s have the same distribution?

Comment: @BCLC For an exchangeable vector, however one permutes its components, we get new vectors with exactly the same JOINT pdf. So, no matter which variable sits, say, in the first position we'll calculate its (marginal) pdf by integrating that common joint pdf in exactly the same way.